# Why is there a difference in user count in GA?

Tags: google-analytics, segment

In Google Analytics, I can see the number of users from Taguchi/ email is 20,876, but when I use those parameters in a segment the number of users jumps to 21,699 (for the same time period), even when compared to All Users - which should be the same as the Source/Medium report. Not sure why this is happening.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the difference is due to data freshness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the number of sessions I think the problem is sampling.

> Sampling thresholds
>
> Default reports are not subject to sampling.
>
> Ad-hoc queries of your data are subject to the following general
> thresholds for sampling:
>
> - Analytics Standard: 500k sessions at the property level for the date
>   range you are using

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192?hl=en

Try to check the shield in top of your report page to verify if it says that the report is based on all sessions or only on a percentage:

[image]

In this second case you should reduce the time interval to have data based on 100% of the sessions.